# Rundeck- connect to EC2 instance node

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, rundeck

I installed ec2 plugin, i can see ec2 node, but problem is that it always shows ec2-user,instead of root, so my ssh connection fails

Followed this guide:https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin

"The default mapping also configures a default username attribute to be ec2-user, but if you want to change the default set:

Mapping Params: ssh-keypath.default=/path/to/key;username.default=my-username"

i specified following mapping parameters on Rundeck server:

```
name.selector=tags/Name
hostname.selector=publicIpAddress,publicI
description.default=Ec2 node instance
osArch.selector=architecture
osFamily.selector=platform
osFamily.default=unix
osName.selector=platform
osName.default=Linux
username.selector=tags/Rundeck-User
username.default=root
ssh-keypath.default=/path/to/key
editUrl.default=https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home#c=EC2&s=Instances
attribute.publicIpAddress.selector=publicIpAddress
attribute.publicDnsName.selector=publicDnsName
tags.selector=tags/Rundeck-Tags
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

it became a habit to answer my own questions :) i needed to add semicolumns (;)

```
name.selector=tags/Name
hostname.selector=publicIpAddress,publicIp;
description.default=Ec2 node instance;
osArch.selector=architecture;
osFamily.selector=platform;
osFamily.default=unix;
osName.selector=platform;
osName.default=Linux;
username.selector=tags/Rundeck-User;
username.default=root;
ssh-keypath.default=/path/to/key;
editUrl.default=https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home#c=EC2&s=Instances;
attribute.publicIpAddress.selector=publicIpAddress;
attribute.publicDnsName.selector=publicDnsName;
tags.selector=tags/Rundeck-Tags
```

Then, mo matter what ssh-key path i specified, i got connection error from Rundeck, so only way was to copy keys from /root/.ssh/ to /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh

Only after that, i got rid of errors